# Fetching data to ReactJs from Strapi deployed on Heroku with Mongo Cloud

Tags: reactjs, heroku, mongoose, cloud, strapi

I currently have a fully functioning backend deployed on Strapi on Heroku using Mongo Cloud.
Strapi works perfectly fine and updates Mongo Cloud whenever I need to.

How do I fetch data from Mongo Cloud to another application? My actual frontend.

Edit: I'm not sure if I'm suppose to set up a mongo server fetch data from mongo cloud or can just use axios to fetch data from mongo cloud straight to reactjs

Answer (score 0):

Fetching data from mongo cloud is a much larger conversation, however you shouldn't be fetching data from mongo (or whatever database you're using) if you're using strapi.  Strapi is a headless API first CMS and the point of using strapi is so that strapi can manage your data for you and all you have to do is to contact the strapi APIs in order to use your data.  If you're using strapi you don't want to manually manage your own data from mongo.

In your strapi CMS you can have a look at the marketplace to install the documentation, then you can open the swagger documentation to see the APIs that strapi automatically generated for you based on your collection types.

After that you can use axios or fetch to get data from those APIs.

Comment: Thank you, my dumbass didnt realize I got to fetch from strapi itself not look for some rest api at mongo cloud